# регулярные выражения PHP / тема в письме

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть варианты строк (это тема в письмах):

```
1) Re: ТЕМА ПИСЬМА
2) Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: ТЕМА ПИСЬМА
3) Re: Re[2]: Re[10]: Re[2]: Re: ТЕМА ПИСЬМА
4) Re: Re[2]: Re[2]: Re[2]: Re[2]: ТЕМА ПИСЬМА
```

Необходимо получить тему: "ТЕМА ПИСЬМА"

Comment: а что тебе мешает удалить все символы до `:` или то го же `Re:`?

Comment: @korytoff в теме письма тоже может быть двоеточие...

Comment: @korytoff    в теме может быть двоеточие, данный вариант не подходит.

Comment: Может конечно, но я за свою жизнь не встречал людей, которые пишут двоеточие в теме письма, кроме `Re:` или `Fw:`

Comment: @Максим147 а если я напишу тему письма "Дружище посмотри на этот крутой iPhone в Re:Store" ?

Comment: Если уж на то пошло, то помимо `RE`, `FW` и `FWD` могут использоваться еще и локализованные аббревиатуры (см. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_email_subject_abbreviations#Abbreviations_in_other_languages)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что удовлетворительный ответ выбран, вопрос решен, обсуждение закрыто

Comment: @cyadvert вчитайтесь в то, что вы написали! Каким образом решенный вопрос автоматически становится не по теме сайта? У нас что, сайт неразрешимых вопросов?

Comment: @PavelMayorov согласен. ошибся. просто вопрос мне вылез на очередь на закрытие. А какую причину тут указывать?

Comment: @cyadvert если вы не можете найти причину для закрытия вопроса - может, и закрывать его не стоит?

Comment: @PavelMayorov - Вы правы. Виноват, исправлюсь... только не я выдвинул его на закрытие... Я мог не поддерживать - согласен...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалить все `Re[..]:`, `Fwd[..]:` или `Fw[..]:` с начала текста

```
echo preg_replace("/^((Re|Fwd?)(\[\d+\])?: )+/", "", trim($str));
```

`$str` - тема письма

Comment: вот такую строку ваше выражение обработает не корректно
"Re:Дружище зацени крутой iPhone в Re: Store"

Comment: согласен. Исправлено...

Comment: да, только снова может быть подстава
" Re: Re[2]: Re[2]: Re[2]: Re[2]: ТЕМА ПИСЬМА"

Comment: это пробел спереди? ну так `trim($str)` его :)

Comment: ну так да ))) но тут опять проблема, я встречал еще в письмах `Fw`
" Fw: Re: Re[2]: Re[2]: Re[2]: Re[2]: ТЕМА ПИСЬМА"

Comment: Хотя в вопросе про это не слово

Comment: @korytoff понятно, что тема письма может быть отредактирована пользователем как угодно, тогда хрен ее какой регухой вытащишь. Но, думаю, автора интересует покрытие максимально стандартных тем письма...

Comment: @Максим147 - если ответ Вас удовлетворяет, поставьте галочку, пожалуйста. Люди! Давайте закрывать отвеченные вопросы!

Comment: @cyadvert спасибо большое

Comment: @cyadvert да , пользователь korytoff оказался прав. Есть еще два варианта: 1)Fwd: Re[2]: ТЕМА ПИСЬМА  2) Re: Re[6]: Fwd: Re[6]: Fwd: Re[4]: ТЕМА ПИСЬМА . какое выражение будет при этом?

Comment: конечно он прав... в вопросе про `Fwd` ничего не было :):):):) Я отвечал на вопрос.... - Я изменил ответ. Он поймает и `Fw`, и `Fwd` - насколько я знаю разные почтовые клиенты разное добавляют